# I receive java.io.FileNotFoundException even though the file exists. Java

Tags: java, jsp, path, filenotfoundexception

I want to create input stream from path string pointing to a jpg file on my computer. However, I receive this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\bnbih\Downloads\tmp.zip\tmp\2227795.jpg (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)

However, the file does exist on my computer and I can create a File object from the same path just fine.

This is all my code for reference:

```
/**detects if the user uploaded ZIP file*/
        if(zipFile.getSize() != 0){

            Path zipPath = Paths.get(zipFile.getSubmittedFileName());//get the path for the zip file
            String zipFileName = zipPath.getFileName().toString();//gets the zip file name with ext

            //create a file system to manipulate the files
            FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipPath, null);

            /**create an iterator over all the individual image files 
             * based on the assumption the the zip file structure is testZIP->testZIP->individual images*/
            Iterator<Path> it = Files.walk(fs.getPath("/" + getRawName(zipFileName))).iterator();

            //while there're images in the ZIP
            while(it.hasNext()){
                //gets the path of the current image
                Path currentImage = it.next();

                //constructs an image file based on path (works fine)
                File currentFile = new File(zipFile.getSubmittedFileName(), currentImage.toString());

                //holds the type of the file (to test if its a JPG image)
                String fileType= new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(currentFile);

                //checks if current file is JPG image
                if(fileType.equals("image/jpeg")){
                  //create path for the current path
                  Path pt = Paths.get(zipFile.getSubmittedFileName(), currentImage.toString());

                  //create input stream based on pt (where error appears even though it is the same path as the File object above)
                  InputStream curImgStr = new FileInputStream(pt.toString());
                  /**make input stream for the file to be inserted as blob in SQL*/

                  //fills zipMap with GUID and image file pair
                  zipMap.put(getRawName(currentImage.getFileName().toString()), curImgStr);

                //Files.copy(currentImage, Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/tesoo/foo" + i + ".jpg"), REPLACE_EXISTING);

                }//end of if that checks if file is a JPG image
            }//end of while 
        }//end of if that checks if ZIP was uploaded
```

This is the entire error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\bnbih\Downloads\tmp.zip\tmp\2227795.jpg (The system cannot
>   find the path specified)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   FileUploadDBServlet.doPost(FileUploadDBServlet.java:115)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is the path from my computer:

> C:\Users\bnbih\Downloads\tmp.zip\tmp and the file is inside it

Comment: You cannot access directly the content of the ZIP file. Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html

Comment: I'm using filesystem API to give access to zip file @ManuelVieda

Comment: `C:\Users\bnbih\Downloads\tmp.zip\tmp\2227795.jpg`. No; it does not exist.